# Signalr Close Message Recieved From Server Error

Tags: javascript, c#, vue.js, asp.net-core, signalr

I have been dealing this error for a long time. I just want to make signalr to listen my 2 method. When i comment the **(this)** methods it works perfectly.
But it doesnt work. Can someone help me? Sometimes i can get the value but then it gets me the error like below the image. I researched some pages but cant find any answer actually.

Vuejs

```
 const hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Debug)
        .withUrl("http://localhost:7002/ChatHub", {
          skipNegotiation: true,
          transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets,
        })
        .build();
      hubConnection.start();
      this.connectionId = hubConnection.connectionId;
      this.connection = hubConnection; 
      hubConnection.on("UserConnected",(users) => console.log(users));(this)
      hubConnection.on(categoryId, (all) => {
        all = JSON.parse(all);
         this.userMessage = {
           id: all.Id,
           text: all.Text,
           userId:all.UserId,
           userName:all.UserName,
           categoryName: all.CategoryName,
           createdOn: all.CreatedOn,
          };          
        this.messages.push(this.userMessage);
        console.log(this.userMessages);
      });
    },
```

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Linq;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Message.Dal.Concrete;
using Message.Dal.Abstract;
using Message.Dal.Model;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
namespace Message.Dal.SignalRHub
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        private readonly IHubContext<ChatHub> _chatHub;    
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor; 
        private readonly IElasticRepository<OnlineUserModel> _elasticRepository;  
        private readonly string _indexName;
        public ChatHub(IHubContext<ChatHub> chatHub,IElasticRepository<OnlineUserModel> elasticRepository,IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _chatHub = chatHub; 
            _httpContextAccessor = new HttpContextAccessor();
            _elasticRepository = elasticRepository;
            _indexName = configuration["elasticsearchserver:User"].ToString();
        }
        public async Task SendMessage(Guid categoryId,string message)
        {          
            await _chatHub.Clients.All.SendAsync(categoryId.ToString(),message);           
        }        
        
        public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {      
            
           var token = string.Empty;           
           var httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies;
           var onlineUserModel = new OnlineUserModel();
           onlineUserModel.Id = Context.ConnectionId;           
           if(!httpContext.Any())
           {
               return Task.CompletedTask;
           }
           token = httpContext.Where(x=> x.Key == "CodeChatBackend").FirstOrDefault().Value;
           if(AuthenticationHeaderValue.TryParse(token,out var headerVal))
            {                
                var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                var val = handler.ReadJwtToken(headerVal.ToString());  
                onlineUserModel.UserName = val.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "Name").Value;           
            } 
            var checkOnlineUser = _elasticRepository.GetUserAsync(onlineUserModel.UserName,_indexName); 
            if(checkOnlineUser.Result == null)
            {
                _elasticRepository.CreateUserAsync(onlineUserModel.Id,onlineUserModel,_indexName);
            }       
            var getOnlineUser = _elasticRepository.GetAllAsync(_indexName);
            _chatHub.Clients.All.SendAsync("UserConnected",getOnlineUser);(this) 
           base.OnConnectedAsync();         
           return Task.CompletedTask;
        }     

         public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
        {
            var httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies;
            var token = string.Empty;          
            var result = _elasticRepository.DeleteUserAsync(Context.ConnectionId,_indexName); 
            var getOnlineUser = _elasticRepository.GetAllAsync(_indexName);
            _chatHub.Clients.All.SendAsync("UserConnected",getOnlineUser);(this)      
            base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);  
           return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        
    }
}
```

When i delete the onconnectedasync client method. It works perfectly. Am i missing something?

[image: Error Code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it! My mistake totally. I was trying to make one hub to connect different methods. To fix this: Create second hub class and configure your startup, then call hub method with a new connection.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this topic ? The problem occurred on the backend or frontend ?
Thank you

Comment: Is this really the expectation? That every individual webhook has its own Hub? I have 4 methods in 1 hub and am also dealing with idle timeouts.